# Could a single person build a single modern computer from scratch

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

By “scratch” I mean, if someone with all the knowledge needed were put in the middle of a plot of land containing all the BASE COMPONENTS (e.g. iron, copper, whatever other materials you would need) needed to build a computer, would they be able to feasibly create a *modern computer* (such as your average desktop pc) by themselves within their lifetime?

Disclaimer: I haven’t seen this **specific** question asked anywhere so not sure if this is the right topic to be posting in. Just took my best guess.

Comment: Yes its possible, but painful and not cost effective.

Comment: Would a clock count as an analog computer ?

Comment: I would think no. Even with adequate money, the number or man-years to even build a fab or design a CPU is greater than many lifetimes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at best it belongs on WorldBuilding.SE

Comment: @joojaa  _[citation needed]_  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Got it, is it ok for me to copy this question over to that thread?

Comment: To have the "knowledge needed", they would have to be an expert in many fields, so the direct answer is no.  Even if "whatever other materials you would need" included a computer with internet access and they were an expert in the variety of fields needed, the answer is still no, because they would need other expertise to build the devices they would need to build the computer.  These devices vary from simulators to drills to resistors.  It is just not realistic.  You are reinventing the wheel without knowledge of the wheel.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Well this is why it’s a hypothetical situation. Obviously it is severely unlikely that anyone would ever be able to have ALL the knowledge needed. However the question is not “Would someone be able to gain all the expertise required”, but rather “IF they had the know-how, could they feasibly do everything on their own within a reasonable human life-span”

Comment: Today's computers are incremental improvements on the backs of others.  All geniuses.  I'd wager most of us would be challenged to implement a crude transistor with the resources available at hand.  Knowledge does not guarantee success.  I spend 20 years to design my computer, but I screw up one transistor and it does not work.  Any answer but no is not realistic.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat i have made some transistors with litography with art students in the student lab. Yield was attrocious and since they were art students nobody was interested to tweak the process, in fact they were happy with somewhat random. Also doing a computer does not depend on one faulty component. Ill grant you that the predictive stuff in modern computers is a bit out there. But having built a computer for th discrete logic gates doing a computer at par with 1980's computer is not hard at all. But skill was not imcluded in the question.